# how to convert UNICODE to string(ANSI 1256) in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have to export a SQL server(2012) view to a ANSI 1256 Arabic Text File.
I use DAtA CONVERTION COMPONENT for converting unicode columns to STRING(ANSI 1256). because input columns are in Unicode.
I face with trunc ERROR, and i need a solution for this task.
Can you give me the solution. thanks.

Comment: If you have a truncation error, then the value you are exporting is too long for the column you have defined. I suspect you forgot to set the column lengths for your csv file (I assume that's what it is, as Excel doesn't "care" about encodes) and thus they are all the default length of 50.

Comment: Also, the title and the problem appear to have nothing in common. Truncation and conversion are completely different things.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i set the length to 4000 in data conversion. and i sure that all values are smaller than 4000.

Comment: But what about in the destination? The conversion transformation size is meaningless if you truncate it when you get to the destination node.